# Unknown Source Error in JNA ( Return Struct Array function in C)

Tags: java, c, struct, jna

I try to make JNA application. However , I can not get sturct array from C. I get error in java side ( **com.sun.Proxy.$Proxy0.fill(Unknown Source)**)

This is my part of c code below. I compiled as shared libary and  I can use other functions. Just giving error when I call fill function .

```
typedef struct A{
    double Value;
    char Type; 
    char Name[100];
    char SymbolTableName[100];
    int updateMode;
    int dataType;
    char ulSize;
} A;

typedef struct B{
    int numAs;
    struct A* as;
} B;

B fill(void){   
    B sVal;
    sVal.numAs=100;
    int i=0;
    sVal.as = (A*)malloc(sizeof(A) * sVal.numAs);
    memset(sVal.as, 0, sizeof(A) * sVal.numAs);
    //X in scope , everything is ok here.
    X= ReadShared(); // It return struct array , X is struct same type.
    for(i=0; i<sVal.numAs; i++)
    {
        sVal.as[i].Value=X->datas[i].Value; 
        sVal.as[i].Type=X->datas[i].Type;
        strcpy(sVal.as[i].Name,X->datas[i].Name);
        strcpy(sVal.as[i].SymbolTableName,X->datas[i].SymbolTableName);
        sVal.as[i].updateMode=X->datas[i].updateMode;   
        sVal.as[i].dataType=X->datas[i].dataType;   
        sVal.as[i].ulSize=X->datas[i].ulSize;           
    }
    return sVal;

}
```

This is my Java Part below.

```
public class TestClass {

    public interface Test extends Library {

        public static class A extends Structure {
            public static class ByReference extends A implements Structure.ByReference{}
            double Value;
            char Type; 
            char Name;
            char SymbolTableName;
            int updateMode;
            int dataType;
            char ulSize;

            protected List getFieldOrder() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static class B extends Structure {
            public static class ByValue extends B implements Structure.ByValue {}

            public int numAs;
            public A.ByReference as;
            protected List getFieldOrder() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }
        }

        public B.ByValue fill();
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public   TestClass(){

    }
    static void funcc(){
        NativeLibrary.addSearchPath("tester", "/root/Desktop/");//Path is true
        Test test=(Test)Native.loadLibrary("tester", Test.class);
        Test.B.ByValue jig=test.fill();

        Test.A[] Avals = (Test.A[])jig.as.toArray(jig.numAs);
    }
}
```

How will I correct this error ? Why it happens? Maybe there is something missing what ı can not see( Java side or c side ). Thanks for any helps.

> at com.sun.jna.Structure.getFields(Structure.java:911)    at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.deriveLayout(Structure.java:1058)   at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:982)   at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.calculateSize(Structure.java:949)   at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.allocateMemory(Structure.java:375)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:184)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:172)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:159)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.(Structure.java:151)  at
>   MyTest.TestClass$Test$B.(TestClass.java:38)     at
>   MyTest.TestClass$Test$B$ByValue.(TestClass.java:39)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:379)  at
>   com.sun.jna.Structure.newInstance(Structure.java:1651)    at
>   com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:408)    at
>   com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:315)    at
>   com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:212)  at
>   ***com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.fill(Unknown Source)***  at
>   MyTest.TestClass.funcc(TestClass.java:63)     at
>   MyTest.t7500.doGet(t7500.java:51)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:562)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:395)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:250)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:302)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: `BsVal;` or `B sVal;`??

Comment: B sVal;  this is my mistake when ı writing to code here

Comment: Show us the stack trace.

Comment: You should re-examine the native to Java type mappings.  Native `char` -> Java `byte`, for one, and an array `struct` field in native needs to be an array `Structure` field in Java.

Comment: Your immediate error is that you haven't implemented `getFieldOrder()` for either `Structure`.  This needs to return a `List` of the structure field names, in order.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined the order of structure fields within your `Structure` classes.  JNA needs this information in order to properly read and write from native memory.

You have also incorrectly mapped native `char` and `char[]`.

For class `A`, you need this:

```
double Value;
byte Type; 
byte[] Name = new byte[100];
byte[] SymbolTableName = new byte[100];
int updateMode;
int dataType;
byte ulSize;

protected List getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("Value", "Type", "Name", "SymbolTableName", "updateMode", "dataType", "ulSize");
}
```

For class `B`, you need this:

```
protected List getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("numAs", "as");
}
```